# C#: convert xml file to csv file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, visual-studio-2010

I have multiple .xml files, all of them having the same node names but different values.  Example:

File1.xml has the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Data><Waf>No</Waf><Name>TEMP\1</Name><Number>0</Number><Iteration>1</Iteration><Lot> </Lot><DateAndTime>11:36:24:35 10/8/2019</DateAndTime><Id>5555</Id><SW>6.40.22.10900</SW><Image>Reference Point 750</Image><Angle >0</Angle ><Algo></Algo></Data>
```

Similarly, File2.xml has:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Data><Waf>Yes</Waf><Name>TEMP\2</Name><Number>10</Number><Iteration>6</Iteration><Lot>99</Lot><DateAndTime>11:36:49:35 10/8/2019</DateAndTime><Id></Id><SW>6.40.22.10900</SW><Image>Reference Point 90</Image><Angle >180</Angle ><Algo></Algo></Data>
```

I use C# (Visual Studio 2010); my goal is to obtain a .csv / .txt file which has first row:

```
Waf, Name, Number, Iteration, Lot, DateAndTime, Id, SW, Image, Angle,   Algo
No, TEMP\1, 0, 1, - , 11:36:24:35 10/8/2019, 5555, 6.40.22.10900, Reference Point 750, 0, -    
Yes, TEMP\2 , 10, 6, 99, 11:36:49:35 10/8/2019, -, 6.40.22.10900, Reference Point 90, 180, -
```

The input to my algorithm would be the name of xml files.  These are the steps I have done till now:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < num_files; idx++)
{
    file_name = file_name + ".xml"; // this contains the name of xml file
    if (idx == 0)   // if I'm reading the first xml file, make a note of all the node names since they will be the column headers. 
    {
      fs = new FileStream(location_xml_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      xmldoc.Load(fs);
      xml_num_nodes = xmldoc.n  ; //.Count;
      Console.Write("\n xml_num_nodes = {0}", xml_num_nodes);
    }
}
```

However,

- The number of nodes xml_num_nodes is output as 2.
- I think that it's unnecessary for me to write this code from scratch and there must be as easier way.  If so, what am I missing?  I am using Linq and saw a fer resources but I'm not able to get what I want.

Comment: Deaserialize xml into a concrete class, Serialize it using a dedicate CSV lib (which will likely just take a concrete class, or interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code if very simple using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp\";
        const string CSV_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";

         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            string[] xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER, "*.xml");
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(CSV_FILENAME);
            Boolean firstLine = true;
            for (int idx = 0; idx < xmlFiles.Length; idx++)
            {
                string file_name = xmlFiles[idx]; 
                XDocument doc  = XDocument.Load(file_name);

                foreach(XElement data in doc.Descendants("Data"))
                {
                    if (firstLine)
                    {
                        string[] headers = data.Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).ToArray();
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers));
                        firstLine = false;
                    }
                    string[] row = data.Elements().Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a class to accept the deserialized XML data, then deserialize each XML file into the class, then iterate on the class members and write the data from each member to a CSV string, then finally write the CSV string to your output CSV file.

Reference: http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11